# Query who will output ONLY numbers in field1 who exceeded a specific threshold

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to make a "simple" query on ORACLE DB who will output ONLY numbers in field1 who exceeded a specific threshold.

In other words, assuming I have the following data in database.

```
FIELD1               FIELD2
=========            ==============
3291234567           333991123456789
3277654321           333011123456789
3481234567           333101123456789
3291234567           333991123456789
3291234567           333011123456789
3277654321           333015123456789
3277654321           333103123456789
3277654321           333201123456789
3481234567           333112123456789
```

I want to output only number in field1 with occurrences >= 3, so the query output will be:

```
FIELD1        FIELD2
=========     ==============
3277654321    333011123456789
3277654321    333015123456789
3277654321    333103123456789
3277654321    333201123456789
3291234567    333991123456789
3291234567    333991123456789
3291234567    333011123456789
```

Please help!!!!
Thanks
Lucas

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you (using `COUNT(*)` as a window function) - I assume you want Oracle even though the question is tagged `mysql`:

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM (
    SELECT field1, field2, COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY field1 ) field1_cnt
      FROM mytable
) WHERE field1_cnt >= 3;
```

Accomplishing this in MySQL is a bit trickier since MySQL doesn't have window functions.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM db_table WHERE field1 IN 
( SELECT field1 FROM db_table GROUP BY field1 HAVING count(*) >= 3 )
```

I believe this will work in Oracle and MySQL.  Using a subquery, you list all the field1 entries that have three occurrences, then the original query is run to match field1 entries in that list.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Referring to additional information from your comments:

Since subquery in this very case is a set of grouped information serving for identification which `FIELD1` values satisfy the condition of having more than 3 occurences in `yourtable` and because of the fact that this additional info is `INNER JOIN`-ed to `yourtable`, it should be enough if you added field filtering with `WHERE` clause in the top-most query.

So the query with `WHERE` clause should look like:

```
     SELECT  A.FIELD1,  A.FIELD2 
        FROM 
        yourtable A 
        INNER JOIN
        (
         SELECT FIELD1, COUNT (1) 
         FROM yourtable
         GROUP BY FIELD1
         HAVING COUNT (1) >= 3
       ) B
       ON A.FIELD1 = B.FIELD1
     WHERE 
       A.FIELD1 = 'some_value'
```

Again, by your last comment, if you have more fields in `yourtable` that you need to filter by, you may add them like:

```
     ..................
     WHERE 
       A.FIELD1 = 'some_value' 
       AND A.FIELD5 = 'some_field5_val'
       AND (...)
```

Comment: You had a similar idea to me.  Some suggestions: putting a field name in count is unnecessary and actually slows down the query.  `count(*)` or `count(1)` is the fastest.  You don't ever use FCOUNT so why declare it or use select the count field?

Comment: Yes, you're right, this could be optimized. Thx for suggestion.

Comment: DAMN T_G :-(
Your query report me on ORACLE 11G:
       ) AS B
         *
ERROR at line 10:
ORA-00905: missing keyword

Please help!!!

Comment: Hi. I'm really sorry for the problem - there shouldn't have been `AS` keyword in the query. I've corrected my answer and now it should be OK. Regards.

Comment: Thank you, now seems it works. How can I add some where clausole like "where field1=xxx and field5=1........" (and yes table contains many other fields that I have to filter :-)

Comment: Hi Lucas. Please find the updated answer. Hoping that it'll help some way.

Comment: I'm really glad I could help you. As for your last comment, I believe that if it's good then thanks to the real Master. Regards Lucas :)